# Python add column with new value when 2 conditions match

Tags: python, pandas, fips

I am trying to add a new column to my data with a FIPS code in it (5 digit number). Basically when County from maindata.csv matches County from fipsdata.tsv, I want the FIPS code (fipsCountyFIPS) to land in a new column i.e. data[fips] (so if County in maindata matches County in fipsdata THEN write the corresponding fips code to a new column in dataframe).

```
data = pd.read_csv ("maindata.csv")
fips = pd.read_csv ("fips2county.tsv",sep='\t')

data[fips] = np.where(data.County == fips.CountyName, fipsCountyFIPS)
```

I also experimented with the following which sounds like it should be easier in theory, though I couldn't work it out :( https://github.com/fitnr/addfips -- I would prefer to just do it with the above if possible.

If anyone could share how to do this that would be amazing!

Update:

[image]

Comment: Typically called [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
# 1. Check if all the counties in the data are in the FIPS data.
#    If so, add a new column to `data` with each county corresponding FIPS code.
if data.County.isin(fips.CountyName.unique()).all():
    data = (
        # 2. Merge the data with the FIPS data
        data.merge(
            fips[["FIPS", "CountyName"]],
            left_on="County",
            right_on="CountyName",
        )
        # 3. Rename the FIPS column
        #    This step is only needed if the column name you want to give
        #    to the FIPS codes is different from the original column name
        #    from `fips` dataframe.
        .rename(columns={"FIPS": "fips"})
        # 4. Drop the `"CountyName"` column from merged dataframe.
        .drop(columns="CountyName", errors="ignore")
    )
```

### Full Example Code

Here's an example of the above code in action:

**Note:** `fips` data downloaded from [https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-united-states-of-america-county](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-united-states-of-america-county/export/?disjunctive.ste_code&disjunctive.ste_name&disjunctive.coty_code&disjunctive.coty_name&sort=year&dataChart=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%3D%3D)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# == Data to run the example ===================================================
# 1. Read in the FIPS data
fips = pd.read_csv(
    "https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/georef-united-states-of-america-county/download/?format=csv&timezone=America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires&lang=en&use_labels_for_header=true&csv_separator=%3B",
    sep=";",
)

# 2. Rename the columns to match the data
fips = fips.rename(
    columns={'Official Name County': 'CountyName', 'County FIPS Code': 'FIPS'}
)

# 3. Make sure the FIPS column is a string and has 5 digits
fips['FIPS'] = fips['FIPS'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)

# 4. Create a list of counties to sample from
counties = [
    "DeKalb", "Johnson", "Linn", "Macon", "Chase", "Hall", "Hitchcock",
    "Pierce", "Rock", "Wheeler", "St. Lawrence", "Wayne", "Buncombe",
    "Martin", "Perquimans", "Scotland", "Vance", "Fairfield", "Lake"
]

# 5. Create a dataframe with a random sample of counties
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {"County": np.random.choice(counties, size=20, replace=True)}
)

# == Actual Solution ===========================================================
# 6. Check if all the counties in the data are in the FIPS data.
#    If so, add a new column to `data` with each county corresponding FIPS code.
if data.County.isin(fips.CountyName.unique()).all():
    data = (
        # 7. Merge the data with the FIPS data
        data.merge(
            fips[["FIPS", "CountyName"]],
            left_on="County",
            right_on="CountyName",
        )
        # 8. Rename the FIPS column
        #    This step is only needed if the column name you want to give
        #    to the FIPS codes is different from the original column name
        #    from `fips` dataframe.
        .rename(columns={"FIPS": "fips"})
        # 9. Drop the CountyName column
        .drop(columns="CountyName", errors="ignore")
    )
print(data)
# Prints:
#
#           County   fips
# 0         Pierce  00139
# 1         Pierce  00069
# 2         Pierce  00229
# 3         Pierce  00053
# 4         Pierce  00093
# ..           ...    ...
# 93        DeKalb  00049
# 94        DeKalb  00089
# 95        DeKalb  00041
# 96        DeKalb  00037
# 97  St. Lawrence  00089
```

**Output screenshot:**

[image]

**If one or more `"Counties"` not found inside `fips`:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed reply. This executes without any errors, however when I run data.dtypes I can't see a new fips column. Here's what I have:

Comment: # 'Data' County column = County. 'Fips' County column = CountyName. 
if data.County.isin(fips.CountyName.unique()).all():
    data = (
       
# Actual fips codes stored in CountyFIPS column
data.merge(
    fips[["CountyFIPS", "CountyName"]],
    left_on="County",  #Is this saying to put the FIPS column next to data[County]?
    right_on="CountyName"  #Is this basically saying we will have County, then CountyFIPS, then CountyName?         
    )

Comment: # I want the fips code column in Data to be named 'fips'
    .rename(columns={"CountyFIPS": "fips"})
    .drop(columns="CountyName", errors="ignore")
    )

Comment: @afroduck the if statement:

"if data.County.isin(fips.CountyName.unique()).all(): ..."

Means that only if all counties from data exist inside the `fips` dataframe we're going to include the "fips" column to `data`. You might not be seeing it because one or more counties from `data` are not present in the `fips` dataframe. I thought you wanted to include such column only when all counties from data are present in the `fips` dataframe. Can you give an example of how the final output should look like? That way I will be able to better assist you.

Comment: Ah I see - Basically I am wanting to do this: If data.County matches fip.CountyName then add fips.CountyName & fips.FIPS to data.FIPS - Does that make sense? Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it!

Comment: @afroduck add them separately or together? E.g.: "| Johnson | 00139 |", or "Johnson00139"? And if only some of the values from `data.County` match `fip.CountyName` do you still want to include the `fips` column, or not? Anyway, I've edited the original solution based on what I understood from your comment. I Hope I was able to help!

Comment: thank you for being so patient. I updated the original post to try and explain a bit better. I am happy to include the FIPS column even if there isnt an exact match for everything! Cheers